# What is myEventProcessor.register?

Tags: java, project-reactor, flux

I am referring to the example of *Reactor 3 Reference Guide: [4.4.2. Asynchronous and Multi-threaded: `create`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create)*.

There is this code snippet:

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myEventProcessor.register( 
      new MyEventListener<String>() { 

        public void onDataChunk(List<String> chunk) {
          for(String s : chunk) {
            sink.next(s); 
          }
        }

        public void processComplete() {
            sink.complete(); 
        }
    });
});
```

#### Unclear

The statement `myEventProcessor.register` is not clear to me.
I don't know how to define the class `MyEventProcessor`.
In IDEA, I couldn't find the class above. The same as the guide.

Is this class needed to be defined by me (the user)?

Answer (score 0):

The instance name starting with prefix `my` indicates, that it is your own implementation.

#### Imaginative assumption of given listener API

In the 3rd paragraph of section [4.4.2. Asynchronous and Multi-threaded: create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create) there might be the assumptive introduction:

> Imagine that **you use a listener-based API**. It processes data by chunks and has two events: (1) a chunk of data is ready and (2) the processing is complete (terminal event), as represented in the `MyEventListener` interface:
>
> ```
> interface MyEventListener<T> {
>    void onDataChunk(List<T> chunk);
>    void processComplete();
> }
> ```

I highlighted the assumption in bold. The docs assume for illustrative purposes that you have a *listener-based API* already. That is:

1. a custom *event-processor* like `MyEventProcesso<T>` that implements a method `register(MyEventListener<T> listener)`
2. a custom *event-listener* that implements the interface given above

#### Example illustrates how to use Flux sink with your listener API

If you now want to use Flux to `create` a bridge to your event-listener-based API. With this method-call of `create` you will register a listener instance:

```
myEventProcessor.register(
  // your given event-listener that uses the sink
);
```

In the example the listener instance uses the `sink` to hand-over events of that chunk of data. So, the listener implementation bridges between your given API and the Flux's sink.

Comment: Got it. Thank you !

Comment: @Kiyose Welcome. Stackoverflow's ettiquette is to [say thank you by voting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)